# Solving a system of ODEs containing a product

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m a math student, but I’ve not yet taken a course on ODEs (though I’ve gone through a fair number of lecture notes and videos on the topic). In some of my personal work I ran into a system of ODEs roughly of the form

$$x_1’ = x_2x_3 + x_2$$
$$x_2’ = x_1x_3 + x_3$$
$$x_3’ = x_1x_2 + x_1$$

More generally, each first derivative is linear in products of the other variables. How could I go about solving the system above? What kinds of systems (if any) of this general form will admit analytics solutions?

Comment: In general you need to be very lucky to find explicit solutions to nonlinear ODEs. For example, the system giving rise to the [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) is about as simple-looking as your system. In your case there is a symmetry in the equations; maybe that can be used somehow?

Comment: You can try to find *first integrals* for this system of autonomous first-order ODEs, i. e. functions $I(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which are constant on the solutions: $\frac{d}{dt}I(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t)) = 0$. For that purpose, the symmetric form of the system may be useful:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx_1}{x_2(x_3+1)} = \frac{dx_2}{(x_1+1)x_3} = \frac{dx_3}{x_1(x_2+1)}
\end{equation}
The knowledge of first integrals can help to reduce the number of unknowns.